# Sampling "nice" mandelbrot sets?

Tags: visualization, fractals

I'd like to randomly sample square Mandelbrot fractals, but I'd like them to be interesting and show a "nice" section of the set:

```
pts = Table[Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2].{1, I}, 2], 10]    
MandelbrotSetPlot[#, Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> {256, 256}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"] & /@ pts
```

[image]

Comment: how exactly do you characterise "nice"? e.g., the ratio of blue to black should be around 0.5?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform So that some part of the fractal is clearly visible

Comment: Something that follows from the informal definition of the fractal is that *every* part of it is interesting.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Excellent question. First I show the result where fractals are sorted from more to less "nice" or "interesting" by going from left to right and top to bottom. This is obvious to the naked eye. In my take we will need two things: staying close to the MandelbrotSet (MS) boundary and a complexity measure to filter out more interesting images. Let's do this step by step.

[image]

### 1. Define a function that approximates MS boundary

`MandelbrotSetDistance` can be used to approximates MS boundary:

```
Row@{ContourPlot[Evaluate[MandelbrotSetDistance[x+I*y]],
    {x,-2.1,.6},{y,-1.2,1.2},MaxRecursion->2,Contours->20,ImageSize->400],
ContourPlot[Evaluate[MandelbrotSetDistance[x+I*y]==#&/@{.2,.1,.01}],
    {x,-2.1,.6},{y,-1.2,1.2},MaxRecursion->2,ImageSize->400]}
```

[image]

### 2. Define boundary approximation as a geometric region

We can now define boundary as a geometric region and we need to do this at high resolution to be really close to the most interesting regions. **HINT:** Play with `MaxRecursion` and proximity `prox` parameter

```
prox=.001;
reg=DiscretizeGraphics[ContourPlot[MandelbrotSetDistance[x+I*y]==prox,
{x,-2.1,.6},{y,-1.2,1.2},MaxRecursion->3]]
```

[image]

### 3. Use RandomPoint to sample fractal frames along boundary

See how sampling works for 1000 random points along the MS boundary:

```
Graphics[{PointSize[.001], Point[RandomPoint[reg, 10000]]}]
```

[image]

Define a function that puts a square of a random size `2d` at a random point `p` in complex plain:

```
delta[d_][p_]:=With[{del={1,1}RandomReal[d]},{1,I}.#&/@{p-del,p+del}]
```

Now sample fractals of random zoom along the boundary. **HINT:** squeezing `d` in `delta[d][p]` gets your higher zoom.

```
pics=MandelbrotSetPlot[#,Frame->False,PlotRangePadding->None,
ImageSize->Tiny]&/@delta[.05]/@RandomPoint[reg,40];
Grid[Partition[pics,8],Spacings->{0, 0}]
```

[image]

### 4. Use image entropy as complexity measure to find "interesting"

`ImageMeasurements[image, "Entropy"]` - image entropy is a quantity which is used to describe the `business' of an image, i.e. the amount of information which must be coded for by a compression algorithm. Low entropy images, such as those containing a lot of black sky, have very little contrast and large runs of pixels with the same or similar values. An image that is perfectly flat will have an entropy of zero. Consequently, they can be compressed to a relatively small size. On the other hand, high entropy images such as an image of heavily cratered areas on the moon have a great deal of contrast from one pixel to the next and consequently cannot be compressed as much as low entropy images.

Images need to be pre-processed before measuring entropy - especially to better identify almost-uniform backgrounds. `GradientFilter` is useful derivative that flattens such backgrounds.

```
GradientFilter[ColorConvert[pics[[1]],"Grayscale"],1]//ImageAdjust
```

[image]

Verify images do have different entropy:

```
measE[i_]:=ImageMeasurements[GradientFilter[
ColorConvert[i,"Grayscale"],1],"Entropy"]
ListPlot[Sort[measE/@pics],PlotTheme->"Detailed"]
```

[image]

Now we can reverse-sort by entropy and it is even obvious to the naked eye that first fractals are more "interesting". You can use this sorting to select the first few and repeat or increases sample size.

```
sort=Reverse@SortBy[pics,measE];
Grid[Partition[sort,8],Spacings->{0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

We can use `MandelbrotSetDistance` to ensure we're close to the boundary and then use the same command to get a good viewing rectangle:

```
SeedRandom[2];
pics = Table[
   c = RandomComplex[{-2 - 1.3 I, 2 + 1.3 I}];
   d = Max[MandelbrotSetDistance[c], 
     MandelbrotSetDistance[c, "Interior"]];
   While[d > 0.2,
    c = RandomComplex[{-2 - 1.3 I, 2 + 1.3 I}];
    d = Max[MandelbrotSetDistance[c], 
      MandelbrotSetDistance[c, "Interior"]]];
   Labeled[
    MandelbrotSetPlot[{c - 3 d (1 + I), c + 3 d (1 + I)}, 
     FrameTicks -> False,
     ImageSize -> 300, MaxIterations -> 150],
    Row[{"c = ", c}]], {4}];
Grid[Partition[pics, 2], Spacings -> {1, 2}]
```

[image]